# How to comment in Komodo Edit

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I used `Komodo Edit` for writing `PHP` scripts and have update `Komodo Edit` to 9.3 version.
Before the update I could use `ctrl+3` to comment, but now it does not work. Now, which keys used for comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find (and change) your keybindings under Preferences > Key Bindings.

Commenting was changed to `Ctrl+/`. `Ctrl+0-through-9` are now used to navigate to quick bookmarks, which are placed with `Ctrl+Shift+0-through-9`.